# Upload file on Digital Ocean Storage Space using form in php

Tags: php, html, digital-ocean

I want to upload file on digital Ocean storage spaces .Please suggest me the best way.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/whats-the-best-way-to-use-digital-ocean-spaces-upload-api-with-a-php-project

Comment: I have used this but i found one error .like  Uncaught exception 'SpacesAPIException' with message '{&quot;error&quot;:{&quot;message&quot;:null,&quot;code&quot;:null,&quot;type&quot;:null,&quot;http_code&quot;:null}}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\spaces.php:510
Stack trac .But i could not fix the error.Please explain.

Comment: You should post the error on the github issue library